# What's wrong with my Scrum TFS charts?

Tags: tfs, charts, scrum

The Sprint Burndown Chart says I have about 150 hours outstanding.

The Sprint Cumulative Flow Chart suggests that I have about:

- 100 hrs 'Not Done'
- 150 hrs 'In Progress'
- 50 hrs 'Ready For Test'

If I sum up the actual SBIs in the sprint I get the following numbers...

- 100 hrs 'Not Done'
- 50 hrs 'In Progress'
- 5 hrs 'Ready For Test'

Can anyone suggest what's gone wrong?

[Sprint Burndown Chart http://www.data-interface.net/chris.arnold/sprintburndownchart.jpg](http://www.data-interface.net/chris.arnold/sprintburndownchart.jpg)

[Cumulative Flow http://www.data-interface.net/chris.arnold/sprintcumulativeflow.jpg](http://www.data-interface.net/chris.arnold/sprintcumulativeflow.jpg)

Comment: Done. I think it's just the Cumulative Flow that's wrong. The Burndown seems to tally with the SBI aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

Almost every time my TFS reports are off in a way where the math doesn't seem to work anymore, I've almost always done one of the following:

- Made changes in the path hierarchy
- Made changes to the iteration hierarchy
- Marked items with a new state by editing process templates

Often it just requires repairing the queries the report server is using.

I recommend running an @project query and see if your current iteration + stuff outside your iteration add up to the numbers you are seeing.